# what's the difference between these three sql queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What's the difference between these three queries, in terms of security but also good coding syntax?

### Query 1

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id,
               user_email,
               user_pass
          FROM user_tb 
         WHERE user_email =\"".$e."\" 
           AND user_pass = md5(\"".$p."\") ";
```

### Query 2

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id,
               user_email,
               user_pass
          FROM user_tb 
         WHERE user_email = '$e' 
           AND user_pass = '$p' ";
```

### Query 3

```
$sql = "SELECT user_id,
               user_email,
               user_pass
          FROM user_tb 
         WHERE user_email = $e 
           AND user_pass = $p ";
```

Comment: first query fails if email is `some"emal@gmail.com`. Second query fails if email is `some'email@gmail.com`. third will always fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one performs string concatenation for the variables ($e and $p), additionallying using the [MD5 function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5) to get the hash of the password for comparison against the `USER_TB.user_pass` column value.  The MD5 isn't any good if the values aren't stored as the hash - because there wouldn't be anything to match against.  Same for vice versa...

The second example lacks the MD5 function use, but properly encloses the variables in single quotes to be treated as string literals for comparison against column values.

The third query lacks the single quoting for proper SQL string handling, and the MD5 function use.

### Summary

All three are susceptible to SQL injection attacks.  If not using PDO, [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) is a solution to using a prepared statement:

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT t.user_id,
                         t.user_email,
                         t.user_pass
                    FROM USER_TB t
                   WHERE t.user_email = '%s' 
                     AND t.user_pass = '%s'",
                  mysql_real_escape_string($e),
                  mysql_real_escape_string($p));

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Note that single quotes are only required in ANSI_QUOTES mode for mysql.  Otherwise double quotes (as in query #1) work fine.  Why did you bring up the concatenation specifically?

Comment: Fair enough, but you didn't mention interpolation in the other queries.

Comment: How exactly is sprintf supposed to replace prepared statements? I think this statement only serves to confuse people. It does nothing different than string concatenation, as far as SQL injection is concerned.

Comment: @Cortopasta: Then the use of `mysql_real_escape_string` in the `sprintf` is lost on you.

Comment: I understand what mysql_real_escape_string is. I was commenting on this potentially misleading statement "If not using PDO, sprintf is a solution to using a prepared statement". Makes it sound like the security comes from sprintf vs mysql_real_escape_string()

Answer (score 2):

All three have effectively no security and are susceptible to any sql injection. You can use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) around your variables, or use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to make this safe.

That being said, placing quotes around your $e and $p variables will only ensure that you don't have a sql error in case those values are null.

Answer (score 1):

They all fail in my book unless `$e` and `$p` have both already been sanitized offscreen.  If that is the case, then #2 wins.  MD5 is a weak hash.  PHP can perform much stronger hashing with `hash_hmac()` sha512, or other libraries (everyone will have something so say) compared to MySQL.  If you are using `md5()` regardless, I would imagine php will perform faster than MySQL here, but that's not a security issue.  Other than that, #1 and #2 are tied.

The problem with #3 is a circumstance where $e or $p might be empty for whatever reason.  Your query will be `where user_email= AND user_pass` and you will get a nasty MySQL syntax error.  They will also need to be wrapped in quotes in addition to other sanitation they might receive or the sanitation isn't going to do you any good.

Edit: as OMG Ponies points out, you need to have consistency with the md5() (or whatever hash) check.  It is my assumption that the password hash is stored and in queries #2 and #3 above, `$user_pass` is hashed by php before being used in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I like "Query 2" too.
And it has 0 security, this is vulnerable to SQLInjection.

You should sanitize the $e and $p strings and make sure it has no bad characters like + /* -- ' " etc